# variable turns to undefined inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, scope, undefined, var

I'm am battling with a javascript function I'm working on.

Inside a for loop I'm iterating all elements with class "visible", inside that loop
I'm preforming two actions.

1. elements[i].removeAttribute("class");
2. elements[i].setAttribute("class", "hidden");

For some reason only 1 is valid. 2 produces an error saying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setAttribute' of undefined
```

Even when I log elements[i] using console.log; after the first console.log call 
the element exists, but on the second console.log elements[i] is 'undefined'

What the hell am I missing here, this is driving me crazy, if my laptop wasn't so expensive 
it would have been broken by now. Help :(

Here's the function:

```
function hide_visable_elements()
{
    // remove body EventListener
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
    body[0].removeEventListener("click", hide_visable_elements, true);

    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("visible");

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    {
        console.log(elements[i]); // Works like a swiss clock

        elements[i].removeAttribute("class"); 

        console.log(elements[i]); // why elements[i] is 'undefined' now ???

        elements[i].setAttribute("class", "hidden"); // << turns to useless code
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a guess.  When you removed 'class', the element drops out of the array, because it no longer fits the criteria.  Have you thought about using jQuery?  It will makes things easier.

Comment: If you have removed the `class` from the element, you have also removed it from the set of elements that has that class. Basically, you erased that element.

Comment: simpler if you use .removeClass() of Jquery.

Comment: @captain I need to have a good understanding of javascript prior to using frameworks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` is a live `NodeList` so changing `className` of the items immediately affects whole list. I would recommend use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) insead.

Plus instead of `var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");` use `document.body`.

Comment: Can you provide the example of querySelectorAll again? I'm learning as I go.

Comment: Thanks. btw why should i use document.body ? performance ? Edit: using document.body doesn't find any body tags.

Comment: `document.body` is convenient shortcut. Why select it if the reference to it is already available?

Answer (score 6):

This is because `getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList`, which is *live*. That is, it updates itself when the elements it refers to change.

When you remove the `class` attribute from an element in the `NodeList`, it gets removed from that list (since it no longer has the `visible` class name).

You don't actually need to remove the attribute. Just setting it will do the job just as well. But since the `NodeList` is changing as you manipulate the elements it contains, you need to count backwards through it (as each time you change one element of it, it is removed so the length decreases by one):

```
for (var i = elements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    elements[i].setAttribute("class", "hidden");
}
```

Comment: The two actions are mandatory in order the achieve the css transition. If that's what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is `elements[i].removeAttribute("class");`  since you selected the element using a class `getElementsByClassName("visible");` . I think so when you remove class attribute completely from the element things are going wrong.

Try some tweak with the code. **You are not suppose to remove attribute class if you are planning to use the same element which is selected using class attribute**.